# NPM request module inexplicable not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, request

I have racked my brain for hours trying to figure out why a simple post request to an API is not working when a form is submitted.  The console shows that the request reaches the API controller address, but the json is missing from the request.  When sent over postman to the same address, everything works and mongoose creates the new MongoDB entry.

Here is my code for the post request:

```
    module.exports.doNewArticle = function(req, res){
//  var postdata = {
//      title: req.body.title,
//      caption: req.body.caption,
//      date: req.body.date,
//      content: req.body.content
//  };
    var path = 'api/newArticles/';
    var requestOptions = {
        url: apiOptions.server + path,
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            title: req.body.title,
            caption: req.body.caption,
            date: req.body.date,
            content: req.body.content
            }
    } 

    request(requestOptions, function(err, response, body){
        console.log(body);
    })


}
```

And the API controller which works when I shoot a request via Postman:

```
module.exports.doArticleCreate = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    // Function for compiling scores
    Article.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        caption: req.body.caption,
        date: req.body.date,
        content: req.body.content,
        methods: {
            sum: 0,
            count: 0
        },
        record: {
            sum: 0,
            count: 0
        },
        stats: {
            sum: 0,
            count: 0
        }

    }, function(err, newArticle){
        if(err){
            console.log("Could not post new article   " + err);
        } else {
            console.log(newArticle + "  HAS BEEN CREATED");
        }
    });


};
```

And the Mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var articlesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    caption: String,
    date: String,
    content: String,
    methods: {
        sum: Number,
        count: Number
    },
    record: {
        sum: Number,
        count: Number
    },
    stats: {
        sum: Number,
        count: Number
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Articles', articlesSchema);
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Try printing out the URL you are creating with `apiOptions.server + path`.  You might be missing a slash between the parts or an 'https://' on the front, for instance.

Comment: it seems like you are making request from one backend server to another backend server is that right?

Comment: I did a console log for the path and it showed a correct URL....also when I submit the form, my API controller creates an entry in Mongo like it's supposed to, except with NO json data.  Everything is blank.  So the API is receiving the put request but not the json data.  If I make the request through Postman, it receives the json data and creates the correct entry.

Comment: Yes I"m using the MVC method with two separate controllers.  One controller handles anything having to do with the view and the API controller serves data from the database.